# Google Maps API - Getting opacity for polygon from geoJSON

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a map with a lot of polygons (11 000), and I want each polygon to have the same color, but with different opacity. The opacity/polygons are stored like this:

```
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[10.927456267537572, 45.68179119797432],
      [10.940290010697588, 45.68157387892596],
      [10.939979018768243, 45.67257819153854],
      [10.927147329501077, 45.672795442796335],
      [10.927456267537572, 45.68179119797432]]],
    'type': 'Polygon'},
   'id': 1,
   'properties': {'cellId': 39},
   'style': {'opacity': 0.38888888888888884},
   'type': 'Feature'}
```

And I want to have the polygon with id 1 to have the opacity stored in the line `'style': {'opacity': 0.38888888888888884},`, and the polygon with id 2 to have a different opacity etc. By default the polygons get shown, but with the same opacity. I'm currently trying:

```
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 46.0840601, lng: 11.1428063}
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson(
        'trentino-grid.geojson');
    }

    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) { //error here
        var value = feature.getProperty('opacity');
        var opacity = value;
        return {
          fillOpacity: opacity,
          strokeWeight: opacity
        };
    });
```

But this doesn't work. I get an error for the line marked with the comment: `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. How can I make the error go away and have all these polygons have their own opacity based on `opacity` in the geoJSON? Thank you!

Comment: Works for me.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a9hpgjpL/1/).  FYI, the strokeWeight is "The stroke width in pixels",  I would suggest using an integer for that.

Comment: I doesn't really work... Try changing the opacity, it stays the same. Also, if I add more polygons, all of their opacity stays the same, too.

Comment: Missed that you have the opacity in the wrong place, it isn't in the `properties` object.  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a9hpgjpL/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the opacity in the wrong place, it isn't in the style object, it should be in the properties object:

```
{
  'geometry': {
    'coordinates': [
      [
        [10.927456267537572, 45.68179119797432],
        [10.940290010697588, 45.68157387892596],
        [10.939979018768243, 45.67257819153854],
        [10.927147329501077, 45.672795442796335],
        [10.927456267537572, 45.68179119797432]
      ]
    ],
    'type': 'Polygon'
  },
  'id': 1,
  'properties': {
  'cellId': 39,
  'opacity': 0.1
  },
  'type': 'Feature'
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a9hpgjpL/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 45.681,
      lng: 10.927
    }
  });

  map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) { //error here
    var value = feature.getProperty('opacity');
    var opacity = value;
    return {
      fillOpacity: opacity,
      fillColor: "#00FF00",
      strokeColor: '#00FF00',
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeOpacity: opacity
    };
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), "click", function(evt) {
    geoJson.properties.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById('opacity').value);
    map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
var geoJson = {
  'geometry': {
    'coordinates': [
      [
        [10.927456267537572, 45.68179119797432],
        [10.940290010697588, 45.68157387892596],
        [10.939979018768243, 45.67257819153854],
        [10.927147329501077, 45.672795442796335],
        [10.927456267537572, 45.68179119797432]
      ]
    ],
    'type': 'Polygon'
  },
  'id': 1,
  'properties': {
    'cellId': 39,
    'opacity': 0.1
  },
  'type': 'Feature'
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="opacity" value="0.8" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="set Opacity" />
<div id="map"></div>
```